# File interleaving, file scanning, file printing

Tags: c, linux, file

Write   a   program that    receives    three   arguments   from    the 
command line:            week09_1 file1.txt file2.txt file3.txt

Your    program should  open    files   file1.txt   and file2.txt   for reading and to  create
file    file3.txt   as  follows:

The first   line    of  file3.txt   is  the first   line    of  file1.txt
The second  line    of  file3.txt   is  the first   line    of  file2.txt
The third   line    of  file3.txt   is  the second  line    of  file1.txt
The fourth  line    of  file3.txt   is  the second  line    of  file2.txt

... 
When    one input   file    reaches the EOF,    the remaining   lines   in  the other   file
should  be  copied  to  the output  file    and the program terminates. Your
program should  print   appropriate error   messages    if  fewer   than    3   file    names
are provided    on  the command line    or  if  the files   cannot  be  opened.

So as of right now i have been able to do what the prompt is asking me to do; however, when one file runs out of lines to print and then it only prints from the other file the printing is on the same line, i am wondering how i can make it start a new line when its only printing from 1 file.

Also i do not understand how i am suppose to implement in the command line arguments the way the prompt is asking.

```
#include <stdio.h>
char line1[256] = { };
char line2[256] = { };
char check;
int END = 0, END1 = 0, END2 = 0;

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  if (argc != 4) {
    printf("Error: Wrong amount of arguments\n");
    return 0;
  }
  FILE *file1 = fopen("argv[1]", "r");
  FILE *file2 = fopen("argv[2]", "r");
  FILE *file3 = fopen("argv[3]", "w");
  if (argv == NULL) {
    printf("Error: file could not be opened.\n");
    return 0;
  }

  while (END != 2) {
    check = fgets(line1, 256, file1);
    if (check != NULL) {
      fprintf(file3, "%s", line1);
    } else if (check == NULL) {
      END1 = 1;
    }

    check = fgets(line2, 256, file2);
    if (check != NULL) {
      fprintf(file3, "%s", line2);
    } else if (check == NULL) {
      END2 = 1;
    }
    END = END1 + END2;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please take into account that lines can be quite long.

Comment: While you're indenting your code: remove magic numbers (e.g. 256), move the “global” variables (actually file scope) into `main()`, check the return values of `fopen()`, and `fclose()` your files when you're done with them.

Comment: The command-line arguments will be in `argv[1]`, `argv[2]`, and `argv[3]` if they're there; in this case, `argc` will be 4. You should validate (at least) how many arguments have been given, and exit with a usage message if `argc` is not exactly 4.

Comment: How long are the input lines? If some of the input lines are longer than 256 characters, then the code has to deal with lines being truncated by `fgets`. Either that, or you need to use bigger line buffers.

Comment: i removed 256 from my actual code.

Comment: When you open the files, you should check that the open operation succeeded. After your `if (check != NULL)` line, the `else if (check == NULL)` test is superfluous (you could use a plain `else` clause).

Comment: Now your code is worse (`char line[] = {};` etc) - I'm not sure it even compiles.  256 is a bit small, but not unreasonably so.  You could use 4096 and ignore the issue, or use POSIX `getline()` and cease having to worry about line length for most purposes.

Comment: i think the basis for this prompt was that the line will not exceed 256 characters

Comment: i still have the problem of when 1 file reaches EOF, the next file keeps printing however it dosent start in a new line. for example in file1.txt there is 1 3 5 then in file2.txt there is 2 4 6 7 8 9 10 in file3.txt it prints out as:1 2 3 4 56 7 8 9 10 all in seperate seperate lines of course.

Comment: Ah, so the problem is that the last line of a file might not end with a _newline_ character.  Instead the end-of-file terminates the line.  So you have to verify that each line has a newline character `\n`.

Comment: how should i do that?

Answer (score 1):

I'll get you part of the way there.

Given this file as `file1.txt`:

```
File 1, Line 1
File 1, Line 2
File 1, Line 3
File 1, Line 4
File 1, Line 5
File 1, Line 6
File 1, Line 7
File 1, Line 8
```

And this file as `file2.txt`:

```
File 2, Line 1
File 2, Line 2
File 2, Line 3
File 2, Line 4
File 2, Line 5
File 2, Line 6
File 2, Line 7
File 2, Line 8
File 2, Line 9
File 2, Line 10
```

You can read them and print them out interleaves like so:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    char buffer[4096];
    char *ptr;
    int i=0;

    FILE *file1 = fopen("/tmp/file1.txt", "r");
    FILE *file2 = fopen("/tmp/file2.txt", "r");

    // while there is something from either file, do...
    while (!feof(file1) || !feof(file2)){
            // use modulo to switch file1, file2, etc
        if (i%2 == 0) {
            ptr=fgets(buffer, sizeof(buffer), file1);
        }   
        else {
            ptr=fgets(buffer, sizeof(buffer), file2);
        }
            // test if the last fgets actually read something by testing ptr vs NULL
        if (ptr)
            printf("%s", buffer);
        ++i;
    }   
    return 0;
}
```

Prints:

```
File 1, Line 1
File 2, Line 1
File 1, Line 2
File 2, Line 2
File 1, Line 3
File 2, Line 3
File 1, Line 4
File 2, Line 4
File 1, Line 5
File 2, Line 5
File 1, Line 6
File 2, Line 6
File 1, Line 7
File 2, Line 7
File 1, Line 8
File 2, Line 8
File 2, Line 9
File 2, Line 10
```

You will need to add the printing to file3, appropriate `fclose` on the files, reading argv, and appropriate error testing/reaction.

Comment: could you explain to me the !feof in the while loop

Comment: It says 'while the system has not detected EOF on one of the two input streams, do ...'.  I'm not dreadfully happy with `while (!feof(fp))` loops, but it is being used safely in this code.

Comment: umm i dont really understand the feof part of the code, and it seems that my code works but its just that after one file reaches EOF it dosent start a new line so when the first line from the next file starts printing it isnt printing in a new line. I would like some help with that.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: `It says 'while the system has not detected EOF on one of the two input streams, do ...'.` It actually says 'while the system has not detected EOF on BOTH of the the input streams, do ...' because it is a logical or.

Comment: @dawg: yup, you're right.  I was semi-distracted at the time (work, or something along those lines).

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: ;-) Funny how work gets in the way

Comment: @user3473994: Part of the reason that you say `its just that after one file reaches EOF it dosent start a new line so when the first line from the next file starts printing it isnt printing in a new line` is because your eof logic is broken. Rather than fix yours I just rewrote it.

Answer (score 1):

I think the code is easier to manage, especially if the last line in the file doesn't have a newline, if you use a function to process one line a file, and call it repeatedly.

```
#include <assert.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

static int read_and_print_line(FILE *ifp, FILE *ofp)
{
  char buffer[64];
  int eol_needed = 0;
  while (fgets(buffer, sizeof(buffer), ifp) != 0)
  {
    fputs(buffer, ofp);
    if (strchr(buffer, '\n') != 0)
      return 0;
    /* Either more to read in current line or EOF without newline */
    eol_needed = 1;
  }
  if (eol_needed)
    putc('\n', ofp);
  return EOF;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  if (argc != 4)
  {
    fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s in-file1 in-file2 outfile\n", argv[0]);
    return 1;
  }
  FILE *if1 = fopen(argv[1], "r");
  FILE *if2 = fopen(argv[2], "r");
  FILE *ofp = fopen(argv[3], "w");
  if (if1 == 0)
    fprintf(stderr, "Failed to open %s for reading\n", argv[1]);
  if (if2 == 0)
    fprintf(stderr, "Failed to open %s for reading\n", argv[2]);
  if (ofp == 0)
    fprintf(stderr, "Failed to open %s for reading\n", argv[3]);
  if (if1 == 0 || if2 == 0 || ofp == 0)
    return 1;
  int r1 = 0;
  int r2 = 0;
  while ((r1 = read_and_print_line(if1, ofp)) != EOF &&
         (r2 = read_and_print_line(if2, ofp)) != EOF)
    ;

  assert(r1 == EOF || r2 == EOF);
  assert(r1 != r2);

  while (read_and_print_line(if1, ofp) != EOF)
    ;
  while (read_and_print_line(if2, ofp) != EOF)
    ;

  fclose(if1);
  fclose(if2);
  fclose(ofp);
  return 0;
}
```

I'm satisfied that this works on its own source code, and also on one 'line' files with no newline at the end (`echo -n Gobbledygook >file1`), and so on.  The buffer is shown as 64 bytes to aid in testing (you could reduce it to 32 or even lower if you like).  Once tested, I'd compile with a size like 4096.

Comment: +1 like the while loop of both then each separately to pick up the end.  Suggest `int r2 = 0` to prevent a problem in the `assert()` if `r1` is EOF right away as r2 is never set then.

Comment: I'd +1 again for the careful handling of long lines and EOF without `'\n'`.

Answer (score 0):

Some UB - code needs fixing

```
//char check;
void * check;
```

Suggest:

```
char line1[256] = { 0 };
char line2[256] = { 0 };
```

Change error check.  Could expand on which file is bad

```
if (file1 == NULL || file2 == NULL || file3 == NULL) {
  printf("Error: file could not be opened.\n");
  return 0;
}
```

But others have a good "rest of the answer".